# Openntf added to ibm domino project but getting illegalstateexception

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have these files: https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino
I created a java agent in lotus domino designer.
I add jar: org.openntf.domino to the java agent.

This is the code in the java agent:

```
import org.openntf.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
          System.out.println("test");
          // (Your code goes here)

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

And run it, then I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory is not initialized for this thread!
    at org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.getThreadVariables(Factory.java:345)
    at org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.getWrapperFactory(Factory.java:627)
    at org.openntf.domino.AgentBase.getSession(AgentBase.java:25)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)



Factory.getSession(); does not work
```

What am I doing wrong here?